# Count word frequency in a .txt file using only dictionary Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've been having trouble getting my program to output the number of occurrences a word appears from an imported .txt file. For my assignment, I can only use the dictionary function (no Counter), and must remove all punctuation and capitalization from a file. We are using Shakespeare's Hamlet from Project Gutenberg as an example ([link](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2265/pg2265.txt)).  I've read other posts in hopes of remedying my situation, but to no avail. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23481119/4494585) by inspectorG4dget seems to illustrate my ideal program code, but when I run my program, a KeyError pops up for the chosen word. Here is my edited program (still receiving the error message with this code):

```
def word_dictionary(x):
    wordDict = {}
    filename = open(x, "r").read()
    filename = filename.lower()
    for ch in '"''!@#$%^&*()-_=+,<.>/?;:[{]}~`\|':
        filename = filename.replace(ch, " ")
    for line in filename:
        for word in line.strip().split():
            if word not in wordDict:
                wordDict[word] = wordDict.get(word, 0) + 1
    return wordDict
```

Here is a desired sample session:

```
>>>import shakespeare
>>>words_with_counts = shakespeare.word_dictionary("/Users/username/Desktop/hamlet.txt")
>>>words_with_counts[’the’]
993
>>>words_with_counts[’laugh’]
6
```

This is what I get:

```
>>> import HOPE
>>> words_with_counts = HOPE.word_dictionary("hamlet.txt")
>>> words_with_counts["the"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    words_with_counts["the"]
KeyError: 'the'
```

Would anyone be able to detect what is wrong with my code?? 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is the word_dictionary function the same implementation in both HOPE and shakespeak modules?

Comment: Yes, I temporarily renamed my program to test out the code.

Comment: 1. Take `wordDict[word] = wordDict.get(word, 0) + 1` out of the if-statement. 2. `for line in filename.splitlines()`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, if I perform your first suggestion, wouldn't that prevent the code from tallying up the frequencies? And if I implement your second suggestion, would I have to remove the second .split() (after line.strip() )?

Comment: No. Since you are reading the entire filecontents into `filename`, `for line in filename` actually iterates over each character, as `filename` is a string at this point. You should be able to verify this with a `print(line)` as a sanity check to make sure I've got it right

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong keys for your dictionary. The loop should be as follows:

```
for word in filename.strip().split():
    if word not in wordDict:
        wordDict[word] = 0
    wordDict[word] += 1
```

Comment: I've corrected that part of the code and am still receiving the same error message. Perhaps it's my calling of the function??

Comment: @Emily I've just had another look and have edited my loop to be correct. Another problem is that `.read()` reads the entire file into a single string. You then loop over that string with `for line in filename`. This doesn't split it into lines, it splits it into individual characters. After removing that loop, it all works. I get 1109 counts (not 993) of the word `the`, however.

Answer (score 1):

```
if word not in wordDict
```

and

```
`wordDict[1]` -> `wordDict[word]`
```

(two occurances)

Why were you counting the length?

Comment: Oh my, that's an oversight I did not catch. Thank you!

Comment: more succinctly, `wordDict[word] = wordDict.get(word, 0) + 1` or use `setdefault`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error came up because of

```
for line in filename:
```

Here 'filename' is a string, not input of a file as

```
filename = open(x, "r").read()
```

was used. 'line' is pulling out every character, not line. Try replacing the code with below function

```
def word_dictionary(x):
    wordDict = {}
    filename = open(x,"r").read()
    filename = filename.lower()
    for ch in '"''!@#$%^&*()-_=+,<.>/?;:[{]}~`\|':
        filename = filename.replace(ch," ")
    for word in filename.split():
        if word not in wordDict:
            wordDict[word] = 1
        else:
            wordDict[word] = wordDict[word] + 1
    return wordDict
```